# Using the Solve function

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I am new to using Mathematica and am attempting to find the roots of a function using the Solve[] function. I can replace $f[x]$ within Solve[] with the actual function and it will work that way, but I am curious as to why it will not work as it is in the picture below.

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my syntax?

[image: My Attempt]

Comment: Please post code as opposed to images of code. Your input gives the same result in both cases you describe when I run it. Most likely you have multiple definitions of `f` and solve is not using the one you intend, executing `?f` can verify this. Try either using `Clear[f]` before defining it, or restart your kernel and run your code again.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[x_] = 2/x + 4/x - 3/2;

sol = Solve[f[x] == x, x]

(*  {{x -> (1/4)*(-3 - Sqrt[105])}, 
   {x -> (1/4)*(-3 + Sqrt[105])}}  *)
```

Verifying solutions

```
f[x] == x /. sol

(*  {True, True}  *)

Plot[{f[x], x}, {x, -4, 4},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol]},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]